# Firefox Stylesheet could not be loaded error

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, firebug, stylesheet

When i open Firefox and Firebug i get this error "Stylesheet could not be loaded. https://salezoo.dk/wp-content/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/style/widget.css"

Also i can't see any CSS rules in the Firebug stylesheet panel?
Every Stylesheet is returning HTTP 200 OK.

I have tried everything i can think off. I am driving myself nuts with this issue.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of what you see? Is the issue really related to Firefox/Firebug or do you also see it in other browsers, too?